# Does drupal can set the minimum resolution for upload image?

Tags: image, drupal, content-management-system, upload

I want to know that does drupal can set the minimum resolution for uploaded images?

I just found only the solution to set maximum resolution for uploaded images.

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What are you using?

I have the FileField and ImageField modules and I can set both Minimum and Maximum resolution (they're one after the other in the manage fields panel).